# How to get properties of dynamic type

Tags: c#, dynamic, expandoobject

I need to get properties of a dynamic object.

I have created this extension method:

```
    public static DataTable ToMyDataTable<dynamic>(this List<dynamic> items)
    {
        var tb = new DataTable(typeof(dynamic).Name);

        PropertyInfo[] props = items[0].GetType().GetProperties();

    }
```

but it props variable returns 0 properties.

How can I do it?

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: So... what is type of `items[0]`?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it is a custom class that has 13 properties

Comment: Please post [MCVE]. It is not really possible for regular type with **13 public properties** report 0 in code you've shown (review https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.getproperties?view=netframework-4.8 to know what to expect)